# Java - Listen to a data forever from an external input

Tags: java, listener

I would just like to ask if how do u listen to a external input forever while u can do events like button clicking, texfield typing, etc.

Like it listens every second, and if it receives a data, it will do something. If it doesnt receive data then it continues to listen for data.

While it listens, I can do events like I mentioned above.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: One way is to start a new thread that does the listening..

Comment: What exactly is the external input?

Comment: from a Socket's data input Sir. (Data Input Stream)

Comment: Yeah - start a new thread.. are you using Swing? If so, you will find [this function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) useful for sending messages back to the main thread

Comment: yes I am using swing Sir.

Answer (score 0):

The only good way to read from a stream is in a separate thread. For a silly example, if you wanted to update a label with the last byte read, something like this might work:

```
static void startListening(DataInputStream inputStream, JLabel label) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                int i = inputStream.read();
                if (i < 0) {
                    updateText(label, "Closed");
                    break;
                } else {
                    updateText(label, "Latest byte: " + i);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            updateText(label, "Error: " + e);
        }
    }).start();
}

static void updateText(JLabel label, String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> label.setText(text));
}
```

Comment: thank you very much Sir. I will try this code now. I will just be right back :)

Comment: how to call this function in another class Sir? (in my case, from another laptop running Java which is doing the DataOutputStream).

Comment: well, you can't just call it from another laptop.. but why would you need to? Right after you connect, simply start listening to the data?

Comment: oops my bad. I mean Where to call this function? In main function? 

or here??

public Server_PC_Pick() {
        
        initComponents();
      
        
    }

Comment: oops, Don't mind that question.
I mean where to call this function in my created form????

In the main function or in this function???


public Server_PC_Pick() {
        
        initComponents();
     
        
    }

Comment: I can't say without seeing your project code, but generally, wherever you obtain/create the DataInputStream?